# A shell script to write selected fields to a single line

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, bash-script, cut

I have a log file `trace.log` which prints the time stamp, thread name and Transaction method and  transaction ID as below.

```
2014-01-23 15:50:41,724 [catalina-exec-35] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1308::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,725 [catalina-exec-33] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1304::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,727 [catalina-exec-10] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1298::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,727 [catalina-exec-24] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1307::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,727 [catalina-exec-12] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1305::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,733 [catalina-exec-10] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1298::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,734 [catalina-exec-26] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1313::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,734 [catalina-exec-26] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1313::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,738 [catalina-exec-39] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1311::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,733 [catalina-exec-35] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1308::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,738 [catalina-exec-27] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1309::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,737 [catalina-exec-22] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1310::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,743 [catalina-exec-30] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1315::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,744 [catalina-exec-39] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1311::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,747 [catalina-exec-2] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1318::
```

I want to `grep` and print the time stamp of the  `getConnection REQUEST` and  `getConnection DONE` for a particular ID in a single line into a file.

I have a written a shell script that printing the time stamp in multiple lines as below.
Here is my shell script

```
for i in {1..800}
do
     echo "Welcome $i times"
     echo "ID=$i, getConnection " >> time.log
     grep ID=$i: trace.log | grep getConnection | cut -d'[' -s -f1 >> time.log
echo "      " >> time.log
done
```

The output is as shown below

```
ID=791, getConnection
2014-01-23 15:50:16,703
2014-01-23 15:50:16,706

ID=792, getConnection
2014-01-23 15:50:16,704
2014-01-23 15:50:16,704

ID=793, getConnection
2014-01-23 15:50:16,704
2014-01-23 15:50:16,709

ID=794, getConnection
2014-01-23 15:50:16,708
2014-01-23 15:50:16,712
```

How I can change that? I need output as shown below:

```
ID=792, getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:16,703 2014-01-23 15:50:16,706

ID=792, getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:16,704 2014-01-23 15:50:16,704

ID=793, getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:16,704 2014-01-23 15:50:16,709

ID=794, getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:16,708 2014-01-23 15:50:16,712
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use shell loops to process text, that's bad practice.

The shell's job is to run commands (the right ones) and make them cooperate to a task.

Here, the right command is the practical extraction and report language interpreter called once, not several commands run (in sequence!) for each line of a file.

```
perl -lne '
  if (/(.*?) \[.*getConnection (.*?), (ID=\d+)/) {
    if ($2 eq "REQUEST") {$r{$3}=$1}
    elsif ($2 eq "DONE") {print "$3, getConnection $r{$3} $1" if $r{$3}}
  }' < your-file
```

Answer (score 1):

you can suppress the newline by passing the `-n` flag to `echo`.

so the following should work

```
for i in {1..800}
do
     echo "Welcome $i times" 1>&2
     echo -n "ID=$i, getConnection "
     grep "ID=${i}:" trace.log \
     | grep getConnection      \
     | cut -d'[' -s -f1        \
     | while read line
     do
       echo -n "    ${line}"
     done
     echo
done  >> time.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close:

```
for i in {1..800}
do
     echo "Welcome $i times"
     echo -n "ID=$i, getConnection " >> time.log
     grep ID=$i: trace.log | grep getConnection | cut -d'[' -s -f1 | xargs >> time.log
     echo "      " >> time.log
done
```

`echo -n` makes sure you do not add a newline, the xargs (default action `echo`) combines the multiline input to arguments.

This way you have the extra line with white space as specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
# cat file
ID=791, getConnection
2014-01-23 15:50:16,703
2014-01-23 15:50:16,706
[...]

# cat file | tr '\n' ';' | sed "s/;;/\n/g" | sed "s/;/ /g"
ID=791, getConnection    2014-01-23 15:50:16,703    2014-01-23 15:50:16,706
ID=792, getConnection    2014-01-23 15:50:16,704    2014-01-23 15:50:16,704
ID=793, getConnection    2014-01-23 15:50:16,704    2014-01-23 15:50:16,709
ID=794, getConnection    2014-01-23 15:50:16,708    2014-01-23 15:50:16,712
```

http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Shell_programming

Answer (score 0):

not shell, but perl you may like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

s{([^,]+,\d+) .*? getConnection (REQUEST|DONE), (ID=\d+)::}{$h{$3}{$2} = $1}e; 

END { 
    for (sort keys %h) {
        printf "%s, getConnection %24s %24s\n",
           $_, $h{$_}{REQUEST},$h{$_}{DONE};
    }
}
```

output:

```
perl checkerbunny < data
ID=1298, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,727  2014-01-23 15:50:41,733
ID=1304, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,725                         
ID=1305, getConnection                           2014-01-23 15:50:41,727
ID=1307, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,727                         
ID=1308, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,724  2014-01-23 15:50:41,733
ID=1309, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,738                         
ID=1310, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,737                         
ID=1311, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,738  2014-01-23 15:50:41,744
ID=1313, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,734  2014-01-23 15:50:41,734
ID=1315, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,743                         
ID=1318, getConnection  2014-01-23 15:50:41,747
```